# Contenteditable deletes first <p> tag

Tags: php, html, contenteditable

So i have a div with a paragraph inside it and some text that is editable.

When you hit enter it creates a new paragraph and this is how i want it to work. When you then delete text and you reach the end, it deletes the paragraph tags but i need it to NOT delete the first one so that when you start typing again its still wrapped in a paragraph tag.

```
<div contenteditable="true">
  <p>This tag cannot be deleted but text is editable</p>
  <p>This tag can be deleted</p>
</div>
```

Currently i have this: `<div contenteditable="true"> <?php echo $text; ?> </div>`

My $text is: `<p>Some text...</p>`

Hope it makes sense what i'm trying to achieve. Thanks beforehand!

Answer (score 1):

What about this?

```
<div>
  <p contenteditable="true">This paragraph cannot be deleted</p>
  <div contenteditable="true">
    <p>This paragraph can be deleted</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry i didnt make it clear but i need the text within the first paragraph editable while the tag itself it not deleteable. Thats why i put the contenteditable on the div itself.

Comment: @christopherlarsen updated. The point is that none of the undeletable p's ancestors can be contenteditable, but the rest can.